# Force mouseleave on CSS menu after submenu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseleave

as you can see here http://www.revistatres.com.br/daniel/trecinco I have a CSS menu with drop-down submenus.

In order to force the submenus to disappear once they are clicked, I used the following:

```
    $("#menu ul li ul").click(function(){ 
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");    
    });
```

and in order to make the submenus re-appear once the menu gets hovered again, I used the following:

```
    $("#menu ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children().css("visibility", "visible");    
    });
```

My problem right now is that even after the submenus disappears, the top menu remains "selected" as if CSS thinks it's still hovered, hence, the background colour remains darker until I move the mouse pointer.

In the $("#menu ul li ul").click event, I've tried these options to force CSS to realise that the pointer is not over "#menu ul li" anymore:

```
            $("#menu ul li").trigger("mouseleave");

            $("#menu ul li").css("removeClass","hover");
```

and a bunch of other things, but none worked.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: your link is not opening, please make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: there was an extra "w", just fixed that, thanks.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Chrome. Ive just tried on IE and the same happens.

Comment: It does happen on mobile safari tho, iPad to be more specific.

Comment: A fiddle should be required for these questions.

Comment: If you put <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/> into the <head> tags, it will relieve that problem on mobile devices.

Comment: I tried on mac Safari and the same happens. Im honestly deeply sorry about my ignorance, but what's a fiddle? Im not a native english speaker

Comment: IE 9, but Im not really bothered about IE compatibility. Im mainly concerned about Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: You can't trigger a css mouseleave event using script

Comment: Actually, you can. If there's a mouseleave event, and you trigger mouseleave, the event catches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `visibility`, You can try `display` property.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/aU68e/)**

**jQuery**

```
 $("#menu ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children().css("display", "block");    
    });

$("#menu ul li ul").click(function(){ 
        $(this).css("display", "none");    
    });
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! i shoud have realised i should use display instead, since the submenus are shown using display upon hovering the headers. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: I tried voting it up but I cant, i was looking for a way to mark this as solved, how do I mark this as answer please? Im really sorry for asking this...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a mouseup event, because the only time the user is going to `mouseup` is after they've clicked a link.

```
$( '#header' ).mouseup(function() {
  //reset header
});
```

I think this is exactly what you want, try it out:

```
$("#menu ul li").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu ul").css('background-color','#ccc');
});
```

Comment: By "reset header" do mean reload the content of the div "header"? If so, I've been using jquery's .load to avoid reloading the entire page when the user clicks a link. This way, I only .load #header and #footer once, I know that by reloading #header upon every click would fix the issue, but that would defeat the purpose of using .load the way I am. I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, if I did, please, do you mind explaining further? Thanks

Comment: No, just reverse whatever changes you made when the user hovered. E.g. if when they hover, the menu option's background color changes from #ccc to #999, in the mouseup function change the background color from #999 to #ccc.

Comment: Check the updated second code block. I'm not sure which of the current two answers is the solution to your problem, but certainly take Surjith's advice. Using display is much more commonplace than visibility.

Comment: I get what you mean now, I had already tried reversing it in the click event, which should be pretty much the same. However, I ran into another problem with that, which should be simple. Initially, "#menu ul li" has no background set, for when its hovered there is                                              #menu ul li:hover { 
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
I tried css("background","blue"); and the header does have its background changed to blue, but how do I remove the background? I tried css("background",""); but it doesn't work.